# How to use `select.select` effectively when client and server inside same file to send and receive from echo server?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

Suppose we have an echo server and a file transfer app.

- There is a sender (`Client`) to send files and a receiver (`Server`) to receive files. The echo server will echo whatever received from the `Client` and the `Server`.
- However, `Client` and `Server` cannot communicate directly, i.e., all packets have to go through the echo server. For example, the `Client` sends a UDP packet to the Echo server, and the Echo server echo that packet to `Server` and `Server` send Acknowledgment to the Echo server, and the Echo server echo that ack packet to the `Client`.
- The objective is to implement a reliable UDP for file transfer. And we have only one UDP socket.

This figure demonstrates what the setup is
[Client, Server and Echo Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PtMM.png)

I have tried to use multi-thread and `select.select` and both do not work perfectly

- The issue with multi-thread is that since `Client` and `Server` cannot communicate internally, and we have only one socket, it is difficult to choose who should send or receive now.
- The issue with `select.select` is that the return list always has `writeable` non-empty, which makes the Client continues to send a bunch of packets before the `readable` is ready.

Here is the implementation for both `Client` and `Server` inside one file (say `transceiver.py`) what I do not use `select.select` (instead using `send` bool variable) but it seems to work fine. But I do believe this is bad practice, so I wonder what can I do to improve my design.

```
def create_transceiver(ip, port):
    address = (ip, port)
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp.settimeout(1)
    inout = [udp]
    client = Client(udp, address)
    server = Server(udp, address)
    client_to_server = True
    send = True
    while True:
        # infds, outfds, errfds = select.select(inout, inout, [])
        if not send: # len(infds) != 0
            if client_to_server:
                server.start_recv()
                client_to_server = False
            else:
                client.start_recv()
                client_to_server = True
            send = True
        elif send: # len(outfds) != 0
            if client_to_server:
                if client.has_ack_all():
                    print(server.write_content())
                    break
                client.start_send()
                client_to_server = True
            else:
                server.start_send()
                client_to_server = False
            send = False
```

Here is the implementation of Echo Server:

```
import socket
ip = "10.10.1.100"
port = 8888
address = (ip, port)

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(address)

while True:
   data, address = udp_socket.recvfrom(2048)
   udp_socket.sendto(data, address)
```

Answer (score 0):

> And we have only one UDP socket.

As far as I understand this objective, you have a server process somewhere (you call it echo server) that is listening on a specific port. Also there is a client that wants to send data to some sort of server.

You provided code shows an implementation of what is called a state machine that (in your case) switches between receiving and sending.

> However, Client and Server cannot communicate directly

The scenario you are describing makes your echo server a classic server that handles  different types of clients. In your case this would be your "client" and your "server". I would like to call these just client-A and client-B. Most tutorials on the internet would call them Alice and Bob, I guess.

> The objective is to implement a reliable UDP for file transfer.

So you want to transfer files between different clients using UDP as the base protocol.
UDP is not very well suited for this purpose. It does not garantee delivery of each packet transmitted. It is possible that packets arrive in different order than they were sent.
Usually you would use TCP for this kind of transmission. UDP is usually used for live streaming data like audio/video calls and stuff like that.
For more information on the differences between UDP and TCP you might check out the wikipedia pages for each:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

It is possible to use UDP for your transfers but you would have to implement all the safeties provided by TCP yourself.

I assume, your client and your server are actually different programs. Otherwise there would be a way they could communicate directly.
If that is the case, this tutorial might give you a starting point:
https://pythonprogramming.net/server-chatroom-sockets-tutorial-python-3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your understanding is indeed correct. I am trying to learn TCP and think implement TCP flow control, error control over UDP would be beneficial. Anyways, do you think the current state machine is a good design? I usually saw people either use `select.select` or multi-threaidng, state machines feels a bit naive.

Comment: Also, Client A and Client B exist in the same file, `transceiver.py`. The problem for me to implement is that since Client A and Client B exist in the same file and they share a socket with the Echo server, I then do not know how to switch socket to the correct client.